# Optimize performance of MySQL UPDATE query containing EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery, query-optimization, exists

Can anybody please give me a hint on how to optimize this update MySQL query that takes about a minute to process?

```
UPDATE store s 
SET reservation=1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM item i 
  WHERE s.reservation=0 
    AND s.status!=9 
    AND s.id=i.store_id 
    AND i.store_id!=0
)
```

I need to update (set reservation=1) all rows in "store" table (which is very large) where there is currently reservation=0 but it's id exists in another table "item". Table "item" is also large but not as much as "store".

I'am not an expert on creating efficient queries so forgive me if this is just a completely wrong attitude and the whole thing has a simple solution.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of the predicates in the correlated subquery could be moved to the outer query. For example, I believe this is equivalent:

```
UPDATE store s 
   SET s.reservation = 1
 WHERE s.reservation = 0
   AND s.status != 9
   AND s.id != 0
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM item i
                 WHERE i.store_id = s.id
              )
```

For best performance of that, at a minimum, we'd want an index on `store` that has `reservation` as the leading column. Also including the `status` and `id` columns would mean those conditions could be checked from the index page, without a lookup of the underlying page in the table.

And for that correlated subquery (dependent query), we'd want an index on `item` with a `store_id` as the leading column.

As another option, consider re-writing the correlated subquery as a JOIN operation, for example:

```
UPDATE store s
  JOIN item i
    ON i.store_id = s.id
   SET s.reservation = 1
 WHERE s.reservation = 0
   AND s.status != 9
   AND s.id != 0
```

If you're running MySQL 5.5 or earlier, you can't get an EXPLAIN on an UPDATE statement. The closest we can get is rewriting the query as a SELECT, and getting an EXPLAIN on that. MySQL 5.6 does support EXPLAIN on an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer - re-writing the subquery as a JOIN actualy performed a lot faster - instead of minutes it took just a few seconds! Adding an index would be even more effective for the future operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
UPDATE store s INNER JOIN item i ON s.id=i.store_id SET reservation=1 WHERE i.store_id!=0 AND s.reservation=0 AND s.status != 9;
```

This case should works faster because you will not go thru all 'item' table each time when you need to check 'store' row.

Comment: Thank you! This query performed a lot faster than that using exists.